# Unable to connect iOS application in Swift to Objective C files using bridging header

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to connect Parse to my iOS application. I make a bridging header and `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` in the bridging header. When I try to call any Parse.function inside my AppDelegate.swift, glitchy Xcode8-Beta3 does not autofill or even know Parse is there, despite the bridging header file being right below it! It throws an Unidentified Parse error. I imported all the frameworks Parse instructed to important. Any ideas or should I just avoid Xcode8 completely and go back to coding Android like the rest of the world?

Comment: I'm not coding Android. It's your own fault if you are trying to use a beta version for production. And it's Xcode 6 by the way.

Comment: And why are you using beta 3?

Comment: Fixed, The correct parse was oddly named Parse 2. I am not greatly fimiliar with the C import statements but I should call #import <Parse 2/Parse.h>

Comment: @jtbandes Beta 3 is the only version I could download off Apple website for free

Answer (score -1):

Clean, clean build folder, rebuild and you should be able to use your imported framework.